# How to make a flat ribbon look like File Explorer Windows 8.1 in Windows Forms C#?

Tags: winforms, ribbon

I want to create ribbon tab (flat style - look like File Explorer Windows 8.1 and Office 2013) in my windows form C# project. Please help me! I try using OfficeRibbon with dll file (https://officeribbon.codeplex.com/) but it only it only Office 2007 Ribbon. Office 2013 is flat style but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use DevExpress  [Ribbon](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2492) .This Tool Provide Ribbon form MDI with document manager and lot of customized controls and Skins for windows form .

Comment: This is a commercial product. Only really applicable if you've got an organization's spending power behind you

Answer (score 0):

The OfficeRibbon control's office 2013 style is almost there, straight out of the box:

[image: Example of OfficeRibbon in action:]

You might need to apply your own theme to get it similar in color to Windows 8. [More on theming HERE](https://officeribbon.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20to%20Create%20and%20Load%20Theme%20File&referringTitle=Documentation)